# navBar and tabs doesn't show correctly using react-native-router-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabs, navbar, react-native-router-flux

Currently I have this structure in my routes.js:

```
 <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login" />
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene drawer key="NavDrawer" hideNavBar contentComponent={() => <NavDrawer username={this.state.userName} />} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} panHandlers={null}>
                            <Scene tabs={true} hideNavBar={false} navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Home'/>} key="homeTab" tabBarPosition='top' tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} lazy={true} drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} />
                                <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="helpTab" title="Help" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="Help" hideNavBar component={Help} title={"Help"} />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="settingTab" title="Settings" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="Setting" hideNavBar component={Setting} title={"Setting"} />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="QRTab" title="QR" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene key="QRScanner" hideNavBar component={QRScanner} title={"QR Scanner"} />
                            </Scene>
                        </Scene>
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```

Problem is on the homeTab, the custom `navBar` (or any navBar at all) won't show.
if I try to remove `hideNavBar` from each of the child scenes, it would just render the `navBar` BELOW the `tabs`.

Can anyone suggest a better way of organizing this? I'm quite a noob with React Native and RNRF.

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with the structure for awhile, this structure represents what I wanna achieve best logically and aesthetically. But I'm just not too happy with how the code looks like. If anyone have any suggestion that can achieve the same logic and looks, with prettier code please let me know :)

```
<Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
                    <Stack key="Auth" initial={!this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene key="Login" hideNavBar component={Login} title="Login" />
                    </Stack>
                    <Stack key="Main" initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        <Scene drawer key="NavDrawer" hideNavBar contentComponent={() => <NavDrawer username={this.state.userName} />} type={ActionConst.REPLACE} panHandlers={null}>
                            <Scene key="homeTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Home' />} drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene tabs={true} tabBarPosition='top' tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} lazy={true}>
                                    <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} />
                                </Scene>
                                <Scene key="itemDescription" hideNavBar component={itemDescription} title="Item Description" back />
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="helpTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Help' />} title="Help" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Help" hideNavBar component={Help} title={"Help"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="settingTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='Settings' />} title="Settings" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="Setting" hideNavBar component={Setting} title={"Setting"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                            <Scene key="QRTab" navBar={() => <PageHeader title='QR Scanner' />} title="QR" drawerLockMode={'locked-closed'}>
                                <Scene>
                                    <Scene key="QRScanner" hideNavBar component={QRScanner} title={"QR Scanner"} />
                                </Scene>
                            </Scene>
                        </Scene>
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```